# Failed to apply plugin: Found java version 11 Minimum required is 1.8. Versions 11.0.0 and newer are not supported yet

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to build the [Minecraft Forge MDK](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/tree/1.15.x/mdk) using IntelliJ 2017.3.4 on MacOS 10.14.6. When I do `gradlew build` I get the following error:

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.minecraftforge.gradle']
>   Found java version 11.0.4. Minimum required is 1.8.0_101. Versions 11.0.0 and newer are not supported yet.`

However, I don't even have Java 11 installed. The project structure is set to 1.8:

[image: project structure]

I switched the IDE boot jdk to 1.8 as well:

[image: switch boot jdk]

And in Other Settings --> Default project structure I also have it set to Java 8:

[image: Default project structure]

Nevertheless, gradle thinks I'm trying to use Java 11. How on earth do I get it to recognize that I am using Java 8?

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '3.+', changing: true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
// Only edit below this line, the above code adds and enables the necessary things for Forge to be setup.
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = '1.0'
group = 'com.yourname.modid' // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = 'modid'

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = compileJava.sourceCompatibility = compileJava.targetCompatibility = '1.8' // Need this here so eclipse task generates correctly.

minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
    // snapshot_YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable_#            Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20190719-1.14.3'
    // makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.

    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            args '--mod', 'examplemod', '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/')

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use, If this is any group other then 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
    // that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency. And it's patches will be applied.
    // The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.15.1-30.0.42'

    // You may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs or you may define them like so..
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version"

    // Real examples
    // compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    // compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // The 'provided' configuration is for optional dependencies that exist at compile-time but might not at runtime.
    // provided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // These dependencies get remapped to your current MCP mappings
    // deobf 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // For more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading by the runtime..
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
            "Specification-Title": "examplemod",
            "Specification-Vendor": "examplemodsareus",
            "Specification-Version": "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
            "Implementation-Title": project.name,
            "Implementation-Version": "${version}",
            "Implementation-Vendor" :"examplemodsareus",
            "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

// Example configuration to allow publishing using the maven-publish task
// we define a custom artifact that is sourced from the reobfJar output task
// and then declare that to be published
// Note you'll need to add a repository here
def reobfFile = file("$buildDir/reobfJar/output.jar")
def reobfArtifact = artifacts.add('default', reobfFile) {
    type 'jar'
    builtBy 'reobfJar'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact reobfArtifact
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file:///${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my gradlew file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

##############################################################################
##
##  Gradle start up script for UN*X
##
##############################################################################

# Attempt to set APP_HOME
# Resolve links: $0 may be a link
PRG="$0"
# Need this for relative symlinks.
while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
    if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
        PRG="$link"
    else
        PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`"/$link"
    fi
done
SAVED="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname \"$PRG\"`/" >/dev/null
APP_HOME="`pwd -P`"
cd "$SAVED" >/dev/null

APP_NAME="Gradle"
APP_BASE_NAME=`basename "$0"`

# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""

# Use the maximum available, or set MAX_FD != -1 to use that value.
MAX_FD="maximum"

warn () {
    echo "$*"
}

die () {
    echo
    echo "$*"
    echo
    exit 1
}

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false
msys=false
darwin=false
nonstop=false
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN* )
    cygwin=true
    ;;
  Darwin* )
    darwin=true
    ;;
  MINGW* )
    msys=true
    ;;
  NONSTOP* )
    nonstop=true
    ;;
esac

CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
        # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
    if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
    fi
else
    JAVACMD="java"
    which java >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi

# Increase the maximum file descriptors if we can.
if [ "$cygwin" = "false" -a "$darwin" = "false" -a "$nonstop" = "false" ] ; then
    MAX_FD_LIMIT=`ulimit -H -n`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        if [ "$MAX_FD" = "maximum" -o "$MAX_FD" = "max" ] ; then
            MAX_FD="$MAX_FD_LIMIT"
        fi
        ulimit -n $MAX_FD
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            warn "Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD"
        fi
    else
        warn "Could not query maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD_LIMIT"
    fi
fi

# For Darwin, add options to specify how the application appears in the dock
if $darwin; then
    GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\""
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin ; then
    APP_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$APP_HOME"`
    CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`
    JAVACMD=`cygpath --unix "$JAVACMD"`

    # We build the pattern for arguments to be converted via cygpath
    ROOTDIRSRAW=`find -L / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null`
    SEP=""
    for dir in $ROOTDIRSRAW ; do
        ROOTDIRS="$ROOTDIRS$SEP$dir"
        SEP="|"
    done
    OURCYGPATTERN="(^($ROOTDIRS))"
    # Add a user-defined pattern to the cygpath arguments
    if [ "$GRADLE_CYGPATTERN" != "" ] ; then
        OURCYGPATTERN="$OURCYGPATTERN|($GRADLE_CYGPATTERN)"
    fi
    # Now convert the arguments - kludge to limit ourselves to /bin/sh
    i=0
    for arg in "$@" ; do
        CHECK=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "$OURCYGPATTERN" -`
        CHECK2=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "^-"`                                 ### Determine if an option

        if [ $CHECK -ne 0 ] && [ $CHECK2 -eq 0 ] ; then                    ### Added a condition
            eval `echo args$i`=`cygpath --path --ignore --mixed "$arg"`
        else
            eval `echo args$i`="\"$arg\""
        fi
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    case $i in
        (0) set -- ;;
        (1) set -- "$args0" ;;
        (2) set -- "$args0" "$args1" ;;
        (3) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" ;;
        (4) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" ;;
        (5) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" ;;
        (6) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" ;;
        (7) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" ;;
        (8) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" ;;
        (9) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" "$args8" ;;
    esac
fi

# Escape application args
save () {
    for i do printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/" ; done
    echo " "
}
APP_ARGS=$(save "$@")

# Collect all arguments for the java command, following the shell quoting and substitution rules
eval set -- $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $GRADLE_OPTS "\"-Dorg.gradle.appname=$APP_BASE_NAME\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "$APP_ARGS"

# by default we should be in the correct project dir, but when run from Finder on Mac, the cwd is wrong
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ] && [ "$HOME" = "$PWD" ]; then
  cd "$(dirname "$0")"
fi

exec "$JAVACMD" "$@"
```

Comment: check your PATH or programs and features, you might have java 11 on the path or installed on your computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> However, I don't even have Java 11 installed.

The error message says: "Found java version 11.0.4."

That means that you do have Java 11 installed.  You might not have installed it yourself, or you might have tried to uninstall it.  But it is definitely there.  Gradle has found the Java 11 installation, and its `java` command has reported its version number as 11.0.4.

Looking at the gradlew script, it is using two methods to decide which Java installation to use:

- If the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set, the script looks for the `java` executable in the installation that the variable points at.
- If the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is not set, it uses the `java` command on the command search path; i.e. according to what the `PATH` environment variable specifies.

So, check what these two environment variables say ... in the shell where you were running the `gradle` command.  I would recommend setting `JAVA_HOME`.  It needs to point to your Java 8 installation directory.

(You can reverse engineer the correct `JAVA_HOME` setting from path to your Java 8 `java` command and what the gradlew script is doing.)

Note that multiple installations of Java will happily coexist on a Mac.  You just need to make sure that your `PATH` and/or `JAVA_HOME` variables point at the right place ... for the version you are currently using / wanting to use.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. Since I really only need this project to point to Java 8, I added the following to gradle.properties in the project's home directory: `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home` and now it works.

Comment: Note to future readers that if you have this same problem your path to the Java home probably won't be exactly the same. If it's on a Mac it'll probably be more or less the same except for the version number; if it's on a PC or Linux it'll probably be somewhere else.